# Find most frequent value (mode) for each variable

Tags: python, statistics, apache-spark

I got a RDD similar to this

```
color  category
green  a
green  b
red    a
orange a
green  b
red    d
green  c
red    d
green  e
```

And I'm trying to find the most frequent category for each color.
Something like this:

```
[green, b]  : 2
[red, d ]   : 2
[orange, a] : 1
```

I'm already half-way there after using

```
rdd.countByValue()
```

Which in this case would return a dictionary like this:

```
(color=u'green', category=u'a'): 1
(color=u'green', category=u'b'): 2
(color=u'green', category=u'c'): 1
(color=u'green', category=u'e'): 1
(color=u'red', category=u'a'): 1
(color=u'red', category=u'd'): 2
(color=u'orange', category=u'a'): 1
```

From this step I have no clue on how to get the most frequent category per color.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm trying a different approach using `contentDF.groupBy('color').agg({'category' : 'max'}).collect()` but I believe `agg` parameter is wrong because it is giving me the overall max of across the whole table. Any suggestions? I feel like I'm getting close!

EDIT: I'm still looking for the solution...
Now I have a table like this:

```
 color category frequency
 green   a         1
 green   b         2
 green   c         1
 green   e         1
 red     a         1
 red     d         2
 orange  a         1
```

Can anyone suggest a Spark SQL query to select the max value of each color group?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
with open("your_file") as f:
    my_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
    next(f)
    for x in f:
        my_dict[x.strip()] +=1
    print my_dict
```

Comment: Does it works on an RDD object? I tried that and didn't worked. Now, I'm using this approach: 

`contentDF.groupBy('color').agg({'category' : 'max'}).collect()`

And Im getting something similar to what I want. I think the agg parameter is wrong.

`contentDF` is the table

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want is:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

result = {color: max(Counter(map(itemgetter('category'), grp))) for
                  color,grp in content.DF.groupBy('color')}
```

But I've never used Spark's RDD objects, so I'm trying to extrapolate from the docs.